# Adding column based on 2 columns of data frame and a key-value list

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have a list of key-value pairs as such:

```
l <- list("A" = 10, "B" = 20, "C" = 30)
```

And a data frame with a vector of values and a vector of corresponding types:

```
df <- data.frame (type=c("A","A","B","B","B","C"),value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df
  type value
1    A     1
2    A     2
3    B     3
4    B     4
5    B     5
6    C     6
```

I'd like to divide these values based on their type's value in my list, such that I end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
df
  type value newval
1    A     1   0.10
2    A     2   0.20
3    B     3   0.15
4    B     4   0.20
5    B     5   0.25
6    C     6   0.20
```

I suspect this is easy, but google has failed me and I've been pulling out my hair for a while trying to figure it out. In python with which I am much more familiar, I could just iterate over the rows and use a dict for my list, but its not obvious how to do that either, nor does it seem appropriate in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about it terms of joining or merging it becomes straight forward.

Note that I would presume value is numeric, not character as it is in your example.

I like `data.table` so will show a way to do this using that pacakge

```
library(data.table)
# df with value as numeric
df <- data.frame (type=c("A","A","B","B","B","C"),value=1:6)
# create the data.table
DT <- data.table(df, key = 'type')
#  create the key-value list as a data.table (specifying the levels the same 
# as in DT[,type]
byl <- data.table(type = factor(names(l), levels = levels(DT[,type])), value = unlist(l), key = 'type')
# note they are both keyed by type, so we can join by type and then
# create a column that is value/ (value in the i component)
# so we use value / i.value
# i.value references value from the i argument (byl in this case)
DT[byl, newval := value / i.value ]
# look in DT now
DT
   type value newval
1:    A     1   0.10
2:    A     2   0.20
3:    B     3   0.15
4:    B     4   0.20
5:    B     5   0.25
6:    C     6   0.20
```

Comment: Yes, the values were numeric, that was a typo in a rush to make a simple example from the actual code im working with, which is considerably more complex and involves a massive data frame.

I hadn't heard of data.table, and it sounds promising, but your code doesnt work:

    Error in value/i.value : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Typo, replace `unname` with `unlist`. (see the edited solution).